# py2exe - Maximum recursion depth error

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, sympy

I'm trying to make executable file of my python program with `py2exe`.
I was succeed to make `hello_word.exe` but when I want to make exe of my own program it said `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`
After trying many times I recognized that it happens when I import `sympy` module.
Should I change `setup.py` when I want to import a module?

Comment: "Should I change setup.py" depends on how it looks now...

Comment: the same az the sample in it's tutorial.
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['hello.py'])

Comment: There's not much we can suggest unless you show some of the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use python 3 and import sys,
see if that helps
py2exe has a problem with sympy,there is and issue in github you can follow

Comment: can you please link to the issue? Also importing sys unfortunately did not help  me.